# mongodb update/append-to nested document

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
{"bar": "blah", 
 "baz": "boo", 
 "quuz": [{"boo": "hi"},   
          {"boo": "lah"}]}
```

Let's say I've got new data that looks like this:

```
{"bar": "blah",
 "baz": "boo",
 "quuz": [{"boo": "whatever"},
          {"boo": "etc"}]}
```

I want to update the document in the db so that it looks like

```
{"bar": "blah",
 "baz": "boo",
 "quuz": [{"boo": "hi"},   
          {"boo": "lah"},
          {"boo": "whatever"},
          {"boo": "etc"}]}
```

Can I do this within Mongodb, or should I just pull down the doc, merge it in my app, and then use `$set` or whatever?

FWIW: I'm using Clojure + Monger.

Comment: Do you only want to merge one array field? And do you know the key for that field in advance? Also, do two fields ("bar" and "baz") need to match for you to merge the documents, or is that arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with `$push` and `$each`

```
db.yourCollection.update({
    bar: "blah", 
    baz: "boo"
}, {
    $push: {
        quuz : {$each: [{"boo": "whatever"}, {"boo": "etc"}]}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in mongodb directly.

1. find the intended object by the common field - in your case, it could either be "bar", or "baz".
2. isolate property to be updated - "quuz"(an array).
3. push new data into the array.
4. save back to database

hope this helps

Comment: Would you mind going into a little more depth? I'm not really a mongo expert. I suspect it involves `$push` and `$each` and some dot syntax, but I'm not sure beyond that.

Comment: not particularly familiar with monger, but going through http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/getting_started.html ,  I will do something like this:   new_data = {"bar": "blah",
 "baz": "boo",
 "quuz": [{"boo": "whatever"},
          {"boo": "etc"}]};      a = (mc/find db "products" { :baz "boo"});  b = a.quuz;  for(x=0;x=new_data.quuz.length;x++){b.push(new_data.quuuz[x])};     (mc/update db "products" {:baz "boo"} {:quuz a.quuz);